# Rails how to get @products in the controller to be passed to another Java Script

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4, datatables, gmaps4rails

I am getting my products index from another custom developed class which is passed to the `index.html.erb` for rendering in a table format, using `DataTables` and `JavaScript` in the `index.html.erb` page. This code is woking very well so far, doing `pagination`, `sorting` and `filtering` on the `server side`, but now I want to get a `@products` variable from the `JSON` used by `DataTables` which I want to process it in the `ProductsController` before it is passed as a `@hash` to another `JavaScript` eventualy to render the `@markers` of the `@products` on a `Google Map`.

Here is my code:

`products_controller.rb`

```
...
  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: ProductsDatatable.new(view_context) }
    end
  end
...
```

`index.html.erb`

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <h1>Products</h1>

      <table id="products" width="100%" class="display cell-border compact hover order-column row-border stripe" data-source="<%= products_url(format: "json") %>">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="text-align: center">Product ID</th>
            <th style="text-align: center">Product Name</th>
            <th style="text-align: center">Category</th>
            <th style="text-align: center">Release Date</th>
            <th style="text-align: center">Price</th>
            <th style="text-align: center">Created At</th>
            <th style="text-align: center">Updated At</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#products').dataTable({
          sPaginationType: "full_numbers",
          bJQueryUI: true,
          bProcessing: true,
          bServerSide: true,
          sAjaxSource: $('#products').data('source'),
          sDom: 'CRlfrtip',
          bStateSave: true,
          responsive: true
        })
      } );
    </script>

Custom class fetching the records from server with pagination, sorting and filtering.

`/datatables/products_datatables.rb`

class ProductsDatatable
  delegate :params, :link_to, :number_to_currency, to: :@view

  def initialize(view)
    @view = view
  end

  def as_json(options = {})
    {
      sEcho: params[:sEcho].to_i,
      iTotalRecords: Product.count,
      iTotalDisplayRecords: products.total_entries,
      aaData: data
    }
  end

private

  def data
    products.map do |product|
      [
        link_to(product.id, product),
        product.product_name,
        product.category,
        product.release_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
        number_to_currency(product.price),
        product.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M%p"),
        product.updated_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M%p")
      ]
    end
  end

  def products
    @products ||= fetch_products
  end

  def fetch_products #this version genertes more optimized queries for the db
    if params[:sSearch].present?
      products = Product
      .where("product_name like :search
        or category like :search
        or date_format(release_date, '%Y-%m-%d') like :search
        ", search: "%#{params[:sSearch]}%"
      )
      .order("#{sort_by}")
      .page(page).per_page(per_page)
    else
      products = Product
      .order("#{sort_by}")
      .page(page).per_page(per_page)
    end
    products
  end

  def page
    params[:iDisplayStart].to_i/per_page + 1
  end

  def per_page
    params[:iDisplayLength].to_i > 0 ? params[:iDisplayLength].to_i : 10
  end

  def sort_by
    columns = %W[id product_name category release_date price created_at updated_at]
    s = String.new
    if params[:iSortCol_0].present?
      s = s + "," + columns[params[:iSortCol_0].to_i] + " " + sort_direction(params[:sSortDir_0])
    end
    if params[:iSortCol_1].present?
      s = s + "," + columns[params[:iSortCol_1].to_i] + " " + sort_direction(params[:sSortDir_1])
    end
    if params[:iSortCol_2].present?
      s = s + "," + columns[params[:iSortCol_2].to_i] + " " + sort_direction(params[:sSortDir_2])
    end
    if params[:iSortCol_3].present?
      s = s + "," + columns[params[:iSortCol_3].to_i] + " " + sort_direction(params[:sSortDir_3])
    end
    if params[:iSortCol_4].present?
      s = s + "," + columns[params[:iSortCol_4].to_i] + " " + sort_direction(params[:sSortDir_4])
    end
    if s.empty?
      s = columns[params[:iSortCol_0].to_i] + " " + sort_direction(params[:sSortDir_0])
    end
    if s[0] == ","
      s.slice!(0)
    end
    s
  end

  def sort_direction (n)
    n == "desc" ? "desc" : "asc"
  end
end
```

How i can get the `@products` in the controller, such a way when user navigates between the pages index pages, to have the content of `@products` changed accordingly?

Comment: It is not quite clear what are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have a controller with an index method. In the view I have a script rendering a paginated table. An additional class is used to construct the array to be rendered in the table. This class is "/datatables/products_datatables.rb". Whatever this class builds as data array I want to be visible in the controller in the index method because I want a second script in the rendering page to put a hash on a Google Map. I need to build the hash in the index with the data fetched from that class to be used by the second script.

Comment: As @Mark H. stated in answer, you can define initComplite and expose `json` variable there, but according to docs, sAjaxSource is only retrieving a portion of data needed for current page, if that is what you want, then it's ok, otherwise you need `ajax`  https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html  and then https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete

Comment: It is already AJAX-ified with this line of code I am using: sAjaxSource: $('#products').data('source'). The portion of the data need is fetched correctly. What I need is to make it visible in the controller to be used by another Java script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the same old problem persisting even after I received advise and I reworked the code. When I am using the navigation buttons for the data table to move to another page, first, last, previous, next etc, the table content changes accordingly, but `the map shows always the same first 10 products`.

The Google Map is never changing when the content rendered in the table changes. How I can fix this?Don't know how to change my code to make it working properly?
What I need is to have the `@hash` content changing when the `@products` is changed with the pagination. How this can be done?

`products_controller.rb`

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /products
  # GET /products.json
  def index

    if params[:sSearch].present?
      @products = Product
      .where("product_name like :search
        or category like :search
        or date_format(release_date, '%Y-%m-%d') like :search
        ", search: "%#{params[:sSearch]}%"
      )
      .order("#{sort_by}")
      .page(page).per_page(per_page)
    else
      @products = Product
      .order("#{sort_by}")
      .page(page).per_page(per_page)
    end

    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@products) do |product, marker|
      marker.lat product.lat || 0.0
      marker.lng product.lng || 0.0
      title = product.product_name
      marker.infowindow make_content_for_infowindow(product)
      marker.json({:title => title})
    end

    @products_data = @products.map do |product|
      [
        product.id,
        product.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z"),
        product.updated_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z"),
        product.product_name,
        product.category,
        product.release_date ? product.release_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") : nil,
        product.price,
        product.current_location,
        product.lat,
        product.lng
      ]
    end

    @json = {
      "sEcho"               => params[:sEcho].to_i,
      "iTotalRecords"       => @products.count,
      "iTotalDisplayRecords"=> @products.total_entries,
      "aaData"              => @products_data.as_json
    }

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render :json=> @json }
    end
  end

  # GET /products/1
  # GET /products/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /products/new
  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end

  # GET /products/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /products
  # POST /products.json
  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /products/1
  # PATCH/PUT /products/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update(product_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /products/1
  # DELETE /products/1.json
  def destroy
    @product.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to products_url, notice: 'Product was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def product_params
      params.fetch(:product, {})
    end

    def page
      params[:iDisplayStart].to_i/per_page + 1
    end

    def per_page
      params[:iDisplayLength].to_i > 0 ? params[:iDisplayLength].to_i : 10
    end

    def sort_by
      #these should be enumerated in the same order as they appear rendered in the table from left to right
      columns = %W[id created_at updated_at product_name category release_date price current_location lat lng]
      s = String.new
      if params[:iSortCol_0].present?
        s = s + "," + columns[params[:iSortCol_0].to_i] + " " + sort_direction(params[:sSortDir_0])
      end
      if params[:iSortCol_1].present?
        s = s + "," + columns[params[:iSortCol_1].to_i] + " " + sort_direction(params[:sSortDir_1])
      end
      if params[:iSortCol_2].present?
        s = s + "," + columns[params[:iSortCol_2].to_i] + " " + sort_direction(params[:sSortDir_2])
      end
      if params[:iSortCol_3].present?
        s = s + "," + columns[params[:iSortCol_3].to_i] + " " + sort_direction(params[:sSortDir_3])
      end
      if params[:iSortCol_4].present?
        s = s + "," + columns[params[:iSortCol_4].to_i] + " " + sort_direction(params[:sSortDir_4])
      end
      if s.empty?
        s = columns[params[:iSortCol_0].to_i] + " " + sort_direction(params[:sSortDir_0])
      end
      if s[0] == ","
        s.slice!(0)
      end
      s
    end

    def sort_direction (n)
      n == "desc" ? "desc" : "asc"
    end

    def make_content_for_infowindow(product)
      s = String.new
      s << "Name: "
      s << product.product_name
      s << " ID: "
      s << product.id.to_s
      s << " Category: "
      s << product.category
      s << " Price: "
      s << product.price.to_s
      s
    end
end
```

`index.html.erb`

```
div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Products</h1>

  <table id="products" width="100%" class="display cell-border compact hover order-column row-border stripe" data-source="<%= products_url(format: "json") %>">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="text-align: center">Product ID</th>
        <th style="text-align: center">Created At</th>
        <th style="text-align: center">Updated At</th>
        <th style="text-align: center">Product Name</th>
        <th style="text-align: center">Category</th>
        <th style="text-align: center">Release Date</th>
        <th style="text-align: center">Price</th>
        <th style="text-align: center">Current Location</th>
        <th style="text-align: center">Latitude</th>
        <th style="text-align: center">Longitude</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="row-fluid">
  <div id="map" style='width: 100%; height: 500px; border: 1px solid black;'>
  </div>
</div>

<br>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#products').dataTable({
      sPaginationType: "full_numbers",
      bJQueryUI: true,
      bProcessing: true,
      bServerSide: true,
      sAjaxSource: $('#products').data('source'),
      sDom: 'CRlfrtip',
      bStateSave: true,
      responsive: true
    })
  } );
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  buildMap (<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
</script>
```

Coffee script for the Google Map to be rendered `gmaps_google.js.coffee`

```
class RichMarkerBuilder extends Gmaps.Google.Builders.Marker #inherit from builtin builder
  #override create_marker method
  create_marker: ->
    options = _.extend @marker_options(), @rich_marker_options()
    @serviceObject = new RichMarker options #assign marker to @serviceObject

  rich_marker_options: ->
    marker = document.createElement("div")
    marker.setAttribute 'class', 'marker_container'
    marker.innerHTML = @args.title
    _.extend(@marker_options(), { content: marker })

  infobox: (boxText)->
    content: boxText
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0)
    boxStyle:
      width: "400px"

  # override method
  create_infowindow: ->
    return null unless _.isString @args.infowindow
    boxText = document.createElement("div")
    boxText.setAttribute("class", 'marker_info_box') #to customize
    boxText.innerHTML = @args.infowindow
    @infowindow = new InfoBox(@infobox(boxText))

@buildMap = (markers)->
    handler = Gmaps.build 'Google', { builders: { Marker: RichMarkerBuilder} } #dependency injection

    #then standard use
    handler.buildMap { provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'} }, ->
      markers = handler.addMarkers(markers)
      handler.bounds.extendWith(markers)
      handler.fitMapToBounds()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this correctly, you can't do exactly what you're proposing. You're dealing with 2 requests. You can expose the data or even the JSON from your ProductsDataTable class as a controller instance variable easily enough and write it into a JavaScript variable in a script tag in the template, but as it sits, you'll still get a second call to get the JSON as soon as the data table initializes.

It looks as though what you're trying to do can be accomplished completely in JavaScript. You can pass an initComplete option to the data table as in https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete. This will call the passed callback when the data has been retrieved.

This will make the JSON data in the table available in the `json` variable passed to your specified callback function. You can then initialize your map in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the kind of solution I was expecting.

In the controller, one single line of code:

```
@json = ProductsDatatable.new(view_context).as_json
```

This makes data available for further processing like this example below.

You can display the entire JSON object:

```
<%= @json %>
```

And slice and dice as wished this json object further.

```
Total Records Count: <%= @json[:iTotalRecords] %>
aaData class: <%= @json[:aaData].class %>
aaData count: <%= @json[:aaData].count %>
aaData first class: <%= @json[:aaData].first.class %>
aaData first content: <%= @json[:aaData].first %>
aaData first content product Product ID (link): <%= @json[:aaData].first[0] %>
aaData first content product Product Name: <%= @json[:aaData].first[1] %>
```

The problem now is that when the page is changed (through table pagination) only the first 10 records are visible not the current 10 records from pages 5, 7, 10, etc.

Comment: Right, just read my previous comment carefully. You have to work on the front-end. Every time you fetch new page, you have to call callback and update the map with new data.

Comment: I reworked further the code and I will post another solution to ask how to solve the initial problem because it is not solved.